# Why i am being charged for azure container apps despite being under free tier

Tags: azure, cost-management, azure-cost-calculation

[image]

Above is the invoice i received today on my email. As i we can see on azure pricing page here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/free-services
[image]
We are given 180,000 vCPU seconds, 360,000 GiB seconds, and 2 million requests for free per month for azure container apps.

Why still i am being charged for azure container apps?

Comment: Container Apps doesn't include Azure Storage or Azure CosmosDB.

Comment: I am talking about specifically azure container the last two entries in invoice

Comment: Do you see anything relevant in the Cost Analysis section of the Subscriptions blade in the Azure Portal?

Comment: Nothing specific i can see in subscriptions blade, also cost of azure container app is showing in Cost Analysis section of the Subscriptions as well

Comment: Sometimes it takes up to 48 hours for your billing to be updated to reflect your usage. Few other possibilities are as follows:

Comment: - Your usage exceeded the free tier limits. 
-   You used a paid feature. 
For example If you use Container Apps with [your own virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/networking#managed-resources) or your apps utilize other Azure resources, additional charges may apply.

Comment: As per MS [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/billing) If your container app has replicas, then by default, replicas are charged at an active rate. Usage charges are calculated individually for each replica. A replica is considered idle only when  _all_  of these following [conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/billing#general-terms:~:text=Usage%20charges%20are,active%20rates%20apply.) are true.

Answer (score 0):

Azure container applications can be either set to Consumption or Dedicated plan. The consumption plan comes with a free allocation above which you are charged

> The first 180,000 vCPU-seconds, 360,000 GiB-seconds, and 2 million requests each month are free. Beyond that, you pay for what you use on a per-second basis based on the number of vCPU-s and GiB-s your applications are allocated.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/container-apps/

If you have chosen a Dedicated plan there is not a free allocation.

It is also worth noting on any account tier you can raise a support ticket with Microsoft for billing-related questions.

Comment: My replica is set to 0-1 which is the minimum value, i can’t set it to 0

Comment: Environment type is showing Consumption only in azure container app overview blade

Comment: Very odd, I suggest raising a billing support ticket in the portal

Comment: I have raised a ticket, but they are saying you are exceeding the free uses. When i checked in metric of the azure container, there was hardly 300 HTTP request per day.  The server is simple CRUD server, it's doing nothing than CRUD with cosmos DB. It was created for learning purposes. But still they are charging, i don’t think it's free

Comment: It's based on the hours of usage (that the app is running at 1 instance) rather than the number of requests. Using metrics you should be able to see how many hours it is set to 1 instance.